# SAX parser does not work in Android Pie (9) and above

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss, saxparser

This xml parsing code (specifically for RSS feeds) works in Android 7 and 8 but not in 9 and Q beta.  `setEndTextElementListener` is never hit.

```
    final RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
    final Element channelNode = root.getChild("channel");

    channelNode.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener()
    {
        public void end(final String body) {
            //this is never hit
        }
    });

    try
    {
        final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200)
        {
            final InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

            Xml.parse(stream, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());

            stream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the URL? Does it begin with `http:` or `https:`?

Comment: I was just about to add an example URL when I saw one that wasn't working had HTTP and one that worked is HTTPS.  So that's it.  Thanks.